# Finding closest triplet in a set of three vectors?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector

Given three vectors of double, I want to pair every element in each vector such that the difference between the largest and smallest element in each triple is minimized, and every element of every vector is part of a triple. Right now, I'm using `std::lower_bound()`:

```
double closest(vector<double> const& vec, double value){ auto const ret = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value); return(*ret); }

int main(){
    vector<double> a, b, c; vector<vector<double>> triples;
    for(auto x : a){
       triples.push_back({x, closest(b, x), closest(c, x)});
    }
}
```

Pretend a, b, and c here are populated with some values. The problem is, `lower_bound()` returns the nearest element *not less* than the argument. I would also like to consider elements less than the argument. Is there a nice way to to this?

Comment: You can use 2 std::min_element to determine that the minimum vector is the vector that has the minimum value. And it could be inside a std::remove_if to remove vectors when they are not the minimal vector.

Comment: In your example, why do you only want to remove the first and not the second vector? As you said, the third has the smallest value of "D" and your second step is to remove all but that one. In total, your requirements are hard to understand. What happens if an element does not share any A, B, or C with another vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to implement a binary search terminating in a comparison of neighboring elements. Another possible solution is to iterate over the elements of each vector/array, adjusting the index as necessary to minimize the difference (which may compare to binary search with an ideal complexity of $O(\log{n})$?):

```
int solve(int A[], int B[], int C[], int i, int j, int k) 
{  
        int min_diff, current_diff, max_term; 
  
        min_diff = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
  
        while (i != -1 && j != -1 && k != -1)  
        { 
            current_diff = abs(max(A[i], max(B[j], C[k]))  
                            - min(A[i], min(B[j], C[k]))); 
  
            if (current_diff < min_diff) 
                min_diff = current_diff; 
  
            max_term = max(A[i], max(B[j], C[k])); 
            if (A[i] == max_term) 
                i -= 1; 
            else if (B[j] == max_term) 
                j -= 1; 
            else
                k -= 1; 
        } 
          
        return min_diff; 
    }
```